# White Screen iOS 9.3 with Ionic

Tags: javascript, ios, ionic-framework

my Ionic app get trapped in a white screen after the splash screen when i run it in iOS 9.3 environment. In major versions (like 10, for example) i didn't get those problems.

I've got those logs on XCode (v8.2):

```
2017-03-23 15:14:12.614 Le Parc SSA[9087:225667] DiskCookieStorage changing policy from 2 to 0, cookie file: file:///Users/hugo/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4A96077C-01E6-4822-A7C7-35D0566CFC06/data/Containers/Data/Application/9E6B94B6-F525-4E03-871F-B17FB53DCF67/Library/Cookies/br.com.leparcssa.binarycookies
2017-03-23 15:14:12.989 Le Parc SSA[9087:225667] Apache Cordova native platform version 4.3.1 is starting.
2017-03-23 15:14:13.018 Le Parc SSA[9087:225667] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2017-03-23 15:14:13.645 Le Parc SSA[9087:225667] Using UIWebView
2017-03-23 15:14:13.658 Le Parc SSA[9087:225667] [CDVTimer][handleopenurl] 0.081003ms
2017-03-23 15:14:13.660 Le Parc SSA[9087:225667] [CDVTimer][intentandnavigationfilter] 1.842976ms
2017-03-23 15:14:13.661 Le Parc SSA[9087:225667] [CDVTimer][gesturehandler] 0.113010ms
2017-03-23 15:14:13.686 Le Parc SSA[9087:225667] [CDVTimer][file] 25.189996ms
2017-03-23 15:14:14.089 Le Parc SSA[9087:225667] [CDVTimer][splashscreen] 402.666032ms
2017-03-23 15:14:14.107 Le Parc SSA[9087:225667] [CDVTimer][statusbar] 17.749965ms
2017-03-23 15:14:14.109 Le Parc SSA[9087:225667] [CDVTimer][keyboard] 1.354992ms
2017-03-23 15:14:14.109 Le Parc SSA[9087:225667] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 450.874031ms
2017-03-23 15:14:14.234 Le Parc SSA[9087:225667] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2017-03-23 15:14:14.469 Le Parc SSA[9087:225667] Finished load of: file:///Users/hugo/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4A96077C-01E6-4822-A7C7-35D0566CFC06/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/27CE3AA4-3D3F-41DF-8D16-E77C6D430322/Le%20Parc%20SSA.app/www/index.html
```

I believe the JS didn't load properly, because I've put some `console.log()` and it doesn't log anything.

Someone have any idea of what could it be?

Comment: Did you find solution to this issue?